# Spark - MLlib linear regression intercept and weight NaN

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have trying to build a regression model on Spark using some custom data and the intercept and weights are always `nan`.
This is my data:

```
data = [LabeledPoint(0.0, [27022.0]), LabeledPoint(1.0, [27077.0]), LabeledPoint(2.0, [27327.0]), LabeledPoint(3.0, [27127.0])]
```

Output:

```
(weights=[nan], intercept=nan)
```

However, if I use this dataset (taken from Spark examples), it returns a non `nan` weight and intercept.

```
data = [LabeledPoint(0.0, [0.0]), LabeledPoint(1.0, [1.0]), LabeledPoint(3.0, [2.0]),LabeledPoint(2.0, [3.0])]
```

Output:

```
(weights=[0.798729902914], intercept=0.3027117101297481)
```

This my current code

```
model = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(sc.parallelize(data), intercept=True)
```

Am I missing something? Is it because the numbers on my data are that big? It is my first time using MLlib so I might be missing some details.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MLlib linear regression is SGD based therefore you need to tweak iterations and step size, see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-optimization.html.

I tried your custom data like this and I got some results (in scala):

```
val numIterations = 20
val model = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(sc.parallelize(data), numIterations)
```

Comment: in Python `model = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(sc.parallelize(data), iterations=20)`